# PHP : fetching image from mysql database (blob type)

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am trying to fetch an image from blob data type. this is the code i'm using

```
<?php
  function showContent(){
        global  $connect;                
        $res= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM  services") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
                echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';

                echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['content'].'<p>';
            echo  '</div>';
        }
        mysqli_close($connect);

    } 
    showContent();
 ?>
```

this is my database table with 1 entry [image]

i get a long string in my inspect element that is something like this

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,Lz.....
```

// this is not complete its pretty long

Please help me whats wrong with this

Comment: check your base64 format is correct or not http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: i copied img src from inspect element and pasted it in above link that did not work , so whats wrong ?

Comment: What is your insert query?

Comment: problem in your base64 image encode format @Sikander

Comment: so can you help me fix this i tried 2  versions that i found in google

Comment: how you encode image ??? @Sikander

Answer (score 0):

For base64 encode you image

```
$img_src = "image/sample.png";
$imgbinary = fread(fopen($img_src, "r"), filesize($img_src));
$img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary);
```

Print image :-

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'" />';
```